# IPA letter: m with vertical straight line underneath

Tags: ipa

I came across the following letter in some documents I'm going through:

[image]

But I can't seem to find this letter in any IPA tables, nor can I find anyway to type this.

How can I find/type this letter?

What's it called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vertical short line marks a syllabic consonant -- when the nucleus of a syllable is a consonant. The interjection *hmm* in English might be transcribed [m̥m̩].

As [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) notes, it's represented in Unicode with combining characters U+0329  ̩ combining vertical line below or U+030D  ̍ combining vertical line above, depending on whether the IPA symbol it's attached to has a descender or ascender.